# How to transforrm a row in header in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame without header.

I would like to set the 500th row as the header (for columns).

I have looked for examples, but I could not find any. Is there any quick solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you provided a reproducible example - it's difficult for me to know what you mean by the "header" of a data.frame.  Are you referring to the column names?

Here is reproducible code to create a data.frame with 500 rows:

```
set.seed(0)
df = data.frame(x=sample(500), y=sample(500), z=sample(500))
head(df)
> head(df)
      x   y   y
  1 449  28 133
  2 133 277 265
```

Here the column names for `df` are "x", "y" and "z".  You can set them with the `colnames()` function:

```
> ?colnames
> colnames(df) = c("a", "new", "header")
> head(df)
    a new header
1 449  28    133
2 133 277    265
3 186 343    342
```

If you want df's column's names to be the values of the 500th row of df, do it like this

```
> colnames(df) = df[500,]
> head(df)
  212 369 214
1 449  28 133
2 133 277 265
```

The first parameter to `[,]` is the row (in this case 500); the second is the column.  Placing no value as the column makes R use all columns.

Comment: Glad to help.  One thing that takes some getting used to in R is that functions like `colnames()` can be used to both get a value and set a value.  I didn't mention it explicitly in the answer, but `colnames(df)` by itself returns the column names.

Comment: That's good to know also. I've started R about 1.5 weeks ago and there are many things I don't get. Anyhow, I like R, because it has many libraries for what I'm doing, and even a beginner like me can get far in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(janitor)
row_to_names(dat, 500)
```

See `?row_to_names` for how to specify whether to keep rows 1:499 and row 500 in the data.frame.

*Self-promotion alert, I maintain the janitor package.  This function was created precisely for this use case so I'm adding it as a late answer.*